# CSS Hover effects

Tags: html, css, hover, effects

I am creating a web site and want to add a hover effect on my buttons by loading another image/button with slightly different color suit that I created in Photoshop.

When I apply the code nothing happens.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
#main{
    position: relative;
    background-color:#ececec;
    height:900px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;

}


    #main .button2{

        position: absolute;
        left:0.5%;
        top: 71.5%;
        z-index:20;
        width:170px;
        height:40px;
    }
    #main .button2:hover{
        background-image : url(images/buttBootsRollover.png);  

    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<article>


<section>
    <a href="#index.php" > <img src="images/buttGloves.png" class="button" /></a>
    <a href="#index.php" > <img src="images/buttBoots.png" class="button2" /></a>
    <a href="#index.php" > <img src="images/buttEqu.png" class="button3" /></a>
</section>

</article>
```

Here is the picture which might give a better overview :
[image]

Eventually I want to add the same hover effect on all of the 9 buttons

Comment: Don't confuse background images with `img` elements.

Comment: You are trying to apply a background image to an image tag. That will not work, you can use javascript to change the src.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this is a bit off. You're setting the background-image property on an element that contains an image which (presumably) takes up the whole space of your element. You're going to give yourself a headache trying to work with that, so rather than explain why you're getting the result you are, I'm just going to tell you not to do it that way and give you a solution:

Get rid of the img elements inside your div elements. Change the background-image property of your button2 class to the image that you want as the default. Leave your .button2:hover property as is.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. but I'm sure you haven't try in Google at-least. I recommend you to follow a simple CSS tutorial first.

```
#main{
    background-color:#ececec;
    height:500px;
    width: 600px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.button{               
        z-index:1000;
        width:170px;
        height:40px;        
        display:block;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
}  
#but_one{
    background-image : url(images/but_one.png);
} 
#but_two{
    background-image : url(images/but_two.png);
} 
#but_three{
    background-image : url(images/but_three.png);
} 
#but_one:hover{
    background-image : url(images/but_one_h.png);
} 
#but_two:hover{
    background-image : url(images/but_two_h.png);
} 
#but_three:hover{
    background-image : url(images/but_three_h.png);
}
```

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        <title>hi css</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
    <a href="index.php" ><img id="but_one" class="button" /></a>
    <a href="index.php" ><img id="but_two" class="button" /></a>
    <a href="index.php" ><img id="but_three" class="button" /></a>
    <div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe to achieve what you want you need the help of `jquery`

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#index.php" > <img src="images/buttGloves.png" class="button" /></a>
    <div class="overlay">play me!</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <a href="#index.php" > <img src="images/buttBoots.png" class="button2" /></a>
<div class="overlay">play me!</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <a href="#index.php" > <img src="images/buttEqu.png" class="button3" /></a>
<div class="overlay">play me!</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
    $(".box").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn();
    }
                    ,function(){
                        $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut();
                    }
                   );        
});
```

Working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/KVN8b/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Just have one background image and hide a bit of it.

For example - double up as demonstrated here http://jsfiddle.net/edheal/Qb7YG

Here is the code

CSS:

```
#wibble
{
    background-image: url(http://well-spun.co.uk/portfolio/technologies/images/rollover.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 14px;
    width: 200px;
}

#wibble:hover
{
    background-position: left -14px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wibble">
</div>
```

The image is 28px high  - just show either the top or bottom half depending if it is hovering.